# Can't Compile Hyperion1.2 with g++ MinGW Compiler

Tags: kali-linux, virtual-machine, g++, mingw

Hey all I'm trying to compile [Hyperion 1.2](http://nullsecurity.net/tools/binary.html) and am getting errors.  Here is the command I am using:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ Hyperion-1.2/Src/Crypter/hyperion.cpp -o Hyperion.exe
```

The errors I'm getting:

```
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x4b1): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::OstreamLog(bool)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x550): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x563): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(char const*)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x572): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x585): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(char const*)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x594): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x5a7): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(char const*)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x5b6): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x5c9): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x5e8): undefined reference to `hyperion::FileInMemory::FileInMemory(char const*)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x62a): undefined reference to `hyperion::PE32Analysis::PE32Analysis(hyperion::FileInMemory*)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x670): undefined reference to `hyperion::FileInMemory::~FileInMemory()'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x695): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x6a8): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(char const*)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x6b7): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x6ca): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(char const*)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x6d9): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x6ec): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(char const*)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x6fb): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x70e): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x72c): undefined reference to `hyperion::createFasmInfileArray(hyperion::FileInMemory*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x763): undefined reference to `hyperion::FileInMemory::~FileInMemory()'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x798): undefined reference to `hyperion::createFasmInclude(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x7cf): undefined reference to `hyperion::FileInMemory::~FileInMemory()'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x804): undefined reference to `hyperion::createFasmInclude(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x83b): undefined reference to `hyperion::FileInMemory::~FileInMemory()'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x860): undefined reference to `hyperion::createFasmKeySize(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x897): undefined reference to `hyperion::FileInMemory::~FileInMemory()'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x8b7): undefined reference to `hyperion::createFasmLogfileInc(bool)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x8ee): undefined reference to `hyperion::FileInMemory::~FileInMemory()'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x975): undefined reference to `hyperion::FileInMemory::~FileInMemory()'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x99a): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(char const*)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x9a9): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x9bc): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(char const*)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x9cb): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x9de): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(char const*)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0x9ed): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0xa00): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0xc04): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(char const*)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0xc13): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0xc26): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(char const*)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0xc38): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(char const*)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0xc47): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0xc5a): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(char const*)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0xc6c): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(char const*)'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0xc7b): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0xd90): undefined reference to `hyperion::FileInMemory::~FileInMemory()'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0xece): undefined reference to `hyperion::FileInMemory::~FileInMemory()'
/tmp/ccKr1FvG.o:hyperion.cpp:(.text+0xfc0): undefined reference to `hyperion::OstreamLog::OstreamLog(bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What happens when you use the supplied Makefile?

Answer (score 1):

After you install mingw-64, run this command:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-c++  Hyperion-1.2/Src/Crypter/*.cpp -o hyperion.exe
```

This is the command needed to compile Hyperion with MingW. The command you are attempting to use has also not worked for me. The above has.

Comment: Please format command output, by indenting command lines by four spaces (see formatting help for more details.) Also, please explain *why* what you are suggesting will fix the issue in the question... It's not completely obvious what is the part that matters in your answer...

Answer (score 0):

You need to first install the package `mingw-w64` (eg. `aptitude install mingw-w64`) before performing the compilation.